# Is there any tool in GCP to patch the Compute Instance?

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have some SUSE, RedHat and Cent OS VM's in Google Cloud. Now I want to patch these servers. Is there any GCP in-built tool or third party tool need to use ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "patch" these servers?  Do you mean run something like apt-get update?

Comment: Patch means Linux kernel updates

Answer (score 3):

@Jannatul, you've asked about "GCP in-built tool or third party tool" in your question.

The answer to the first part of the question regards "GCP in-built tool" is "No". The OS deployment images in GCE are kept updated, but after deployment it's up-to-you how to keep VM instances patched. At this time Google does not provide any cloud service for that purpose since such a tool is out of scope of IaaS that the GCE actually is.

As for the second part ("third party tool"), an approach to Linux patching is not GCP-specific, it should be similar to that you use in the private datacenter. Since you use commercial Linux'es, including Red Hat and Suse, that vendors' solutions could work for your needs: for example [Suse Manager](https://www.suse.com/products/suse-manager/) or [Red Hat Satellite](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/management/satellite) (both originate from Spacewalk and support various Linux clients), as well as open-source [Spacewalk Project](https://spacewalkproject.github.io/) solution itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understood that GCP doesn't have their own tool to patch the servers. Anyone knows which tools are being used most to patch the servers in GCP?

Comment: The answer is extended

Answer (score 1):

GCP now has a built-in VM patching service, a part of VM Manager suite: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/os-patch-management

Users can get patch compliance reports and perform manual or automatic scheduled updates of Ubuntu, Debian, RHEL, SLES, Windows VMs.

Service is free for the first 100 VMs.